# Auto run two vba codes when an Excel workbook opens

Tags: excel, vba

I have two VBA codes I would like to run when the Excel workbook is opened.

```
Sub test2()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("A1:A1").Cells
        c.Select
        SendKeys "{F2}", True
        SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xCell As Range
    If Target.Address <> Range("A1").Address Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xCell In Range("B3:P3")
        xCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = (xCell.Value < Target.Value)
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It runs perfectly manually.

I have tried `Sub Workbook_Open`, but it does not work.
I have tried in module, in sheet and in `ThisWorkbook` too.
Could not make it work automatically as the workbook opens.

This code is supposed to F2+Enter cell A1 and then hide some columns depending on value in A1.

I modified code in this way:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
     test2
End Sub
Sub test2()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Sheets("MySheet").Range("A1:A1").Cells
        c.Select
        SendKeys "{F2}", True
        SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xCell As Range
    If Target.Address <> Range("A1").Address Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xCell In Range("B3:P3")
        xCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = (xCell.Value < Target.Value)
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

When openning worksheet it starts performing, does the first part (F2+Enter), but stops there. Does not perform this part:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        Dim xCell As Range
        If Target.Address <> Range("A1").Address Then Exit Sub
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each xCell In Range("B3:P3")
            xCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = (xCell.Value < Target.Value)
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Code writen in Sheet1 (not "ThisWorkbook") manually performs well (not automatically).

The same code writen in "ThisWorkbook" starts performing automatically when file opens, but stops in the middle (as mentions earlier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're doing an over-engineering here. 
Currently you want to:

- Call on open `Workbook_Open`
- ... the macro `test2` which simulates a change in the sheet (by pressing F2 and Enter), so that...
- ... the code inside `Worksheet_Change` gets called.

In fact, what you really want is to have the code that is now inside `Worksheet_Change` inside `Workbook_Open`.

So:

1. Remove `test2`
2. Remove the code from `Worksheet_Change`
3. Add your code directly inside `Workbook_Open` as follows:

   ```
   Private Sub Workbook_Open()
       Dim xCell As Range
       Dim Target As Range: Set Target = Sheets("yourSheet").Range("A1")
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       For Each xCell In Sheets("yourSheet").Range("B3:P3")
           xCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = (xCell.Value < Target.Value)
       Next
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thank you for you quick answer.
 My code was in `sheet` and it worked **manually**

Comment: Thank you for you quick answer.
 My code was in `sheet` and it worked **manually**. As I used your code (not automation part) in `Thisworkbook` it runs manually only the first part, that is F2+Enter. It stops there. It **does not proceed** to `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`.  Also please explain how to use `Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'call macro test2 
     test2
End Sub`         Thank you in advance.

Comment: @dgoldi as you made your event for the sheet change.c you click on “ThisWorkbook” on the left side of your editor, in the project tree, and you write your code in there.

Comment: The same code writen in Sheet1 (not "ThisWorkbook") manually performs well (not automatically).

The same code writen in "ThisWorkbook" starts performing automatically when file opens, but stops in the middle (as mentions earlier).

There should be some combination. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: @d.goldi can you explain me in words what you're trying to do with your macro `test2`?

Comment: I have scadule with dates in B3:P3 and today function in A1. When opening workbook, I would like to hide colomns that have dates less than in A1.

Comment: test2 starts with "pushing" F2 and then Enter, and continues by hiding colomns. it works when writen in Sheet1 and manually lounched

Comment: @d.goldi the hiding column is in the `Worksheet_Change` event. If I only read at `test2`, you just enter the cell (F2) and confirm the value (Enter). Is this some sort of workaround you apply to call the code in `Worksheet_Change`?

Comment: @ MatteoNNZ Yes, exactly. 'test2' is to call the code 'Worksheet_Change'.  I could not find another solution to do it automatically.

Comment: @d.goldi ok, so I'm modifying my answer for that.

Comment: Can the code be modified in order to run the same action on all sheets (the ranges are same)?

Comment: @d.goldi yes it can, just wrap your code into an outer loop like `For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets` and then use `sht` every time you call a `Range` or `Cell` to make sure it runs into the good sheet.